# I Got f.getClientRects is not a function error due in my project i use juqery.min.js file 2 times in layout for different purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is first ,

1. src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"

This is 2nd ,
2. src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js".

both are needed because, i have use some third party control,
out if this some control need first and some need 2nd.
Help?

Comment: Why do you need both? They look like they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load **juqery.min.js** file 2 times in layout for different purpose use **jQuery.noConflict():**

```
<!-- load local jQuery 3_2_1 -->
    <script  src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_local_3_2_1 = $.noConflict(true);
        </script>
<!-- load jQuery 3.2.1 -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_3_2_1= $.noConflict(true);
        </script>
```